# I'm trying to create model classes the json_serializable way. build_runner build runs without errors but doesn't build the necessary file

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create model classes the json_serializable way. I copied the code directly from the flutter documentation. This is my items.dart file -

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'user.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class User {
  User(this.name, this.email);

  String name;
  String email;

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this);
}
```

When I run `flutter pub run build_runner build` I don't get any errors but I do get a warning -

```
[WARNING] json_serializable:json_serializable on lib/items.dart: Missing "part 'items.g.dart';"
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here are the versions I've used - 
  json_annotation: 3.0.1 
  build_runner: 1.7.3 
  json_serializable: 3.2.5

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable/issues/424
check out this one
or try this 

> flutter packages pub run build_runner clean
> flutter packages pub run build_runner build --verbose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the name of the file from `items.dart` to `user.dart`.
Rebuild using `--delete-conflicting-outputs`